# Custom search in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I am working on a requirement where i have a table and on each column of table i have a text box  for searching that column.the columns include Name(text),DateofHike(date),Gender(text),Salary(number),Salary(number).when i searched Salary for the first time it is working when i cleared the text and searched for Name it is not bringing the searched results.

My js file code

```
var FilterApp = angular.module("FilterModule", []);
FilterApp
    .controller("RowsToDisplay", function ($scope) {
        var EmpDetails = [
            { name: "phani_1", DOB: new Date("November 9 2008"), Gender: "Male", SalaryNumber: 8000 },
            { name: "phani_2", DOB: new Date("January 31 2010"), Gender: "Male", SalaryNumber: 17200 },
            { name: "phani_7", DOB: new Date("October 31 2012"), Gender: "Male", SalaryNumber: 23500 },
            { name: "phani_4", DOB: new Date("October 11 2012"), Gender: "Male", SalaryNumber: 2500 },
            { name: "phani_5", DOB: new Date("November 30 2013"), Gender: "Male", SalaryNumber: 41750 },
            { name: "phani_6", DOB: new Date("December 31 2014"), Gender: "Male", SalaryNumber: 48450 }
        ];       
        $scope.funSearch = function (item) {
            if ($scope.SearchText == undefined) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                if ($scope.SearchText.name != undefined) {
                    if (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.SearchText.name.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                else if ($scope.SearchText.Gender != undefined) {
                    if (item.Gender.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.SearchText.Gender.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                else if ($scope.SearchText.SalaryNumber != undefined) {
                    var compare = item.SalaryNumber.toString();
                    var comparer = $scope.SearchText.SalaryNumber;
                    alert(comparer);
                    if (compare.indexOf(comparer) != -1) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

my html code

```
<tr>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Search name" ng-model="SearchText.name" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Search DOB" ng-model="SearchText.DOB" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Search Gender" ng-model="SearchText.Gender" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Search SalaryNumber" ng-model="SearchText.SalaryNumber" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Search currency" ng-model="SearchText.SalaryNumber" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="objEmpDetail in EmpDetails | orderBy:sortColumn:reverseSort | filter:funSearch">
                    <td>{{objEmpDetail.name | uppercase}}</td>
                    <td>{{objEmpDetail.DOB|date:"dd/MM/yy"}}</td>
                    <td>{{objEmpDetail.Gender|lowercase}}</td>
                    <td>{{objEmpDetail.SalaryNumber| number:2}}</td>
                    <td>{{objEmpDetail.SalaryNumber| currency:"$":1}}</td>
                </tr>
```

Please suggest me.

Comment: please edit the question and use Code Sample button in the editor to format your code properly

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using Angular's `filter` and passing it your `funSearch` function that is in your controller. If you want to use it as a filter you better build a custom filter and register it to your app. 
Look at this reference for building a custom filter: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter